# What is a tight narrow space between things that are in tight contact with each other called in everyday English?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

[image]

This is a picture of my sofa. There is a tight space between the arm and the seat of the sofa.

If you have a cover, you can tuck the cover in this tight gap.

Is that tight space called a gap?

For example, *there is a toy stuck in the gap in the sofa*.

But "**a gap**" has quite a big space.

I did my research and it seems to be called "**crevice**". But I want a common word that is used in everyday English.

**What is a tight narrow space between things that are in tight contact with each other called in everyday English?**

Comment: Could also be called a **seam**.

Comment: I don't agree that the word gap requires a large space. A gap can be small or large. The space between two teeth is often referred to as a gap, and it can be wide or narrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We usually refer to a tight narrow gap like that as [the ***crack*** between the cushions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20*%20between%20the%20cushions&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20), or between the side/back of a sofa and the seat cushions...

[image]

Comment: Apparently, the *gap* between the cushions went into hiding in the 60s.... I know that it's probably just an artifact of imperfect data, but it always seems weird when there's an abrupt change in one specific phrasing like that.

Comment: As kids, we just looked ***down the back*** or ***down the side** of the sofa* after guests left. But we *might* have also checked the ***gap/s*** between the seat cushions themselves. But of course, those gaps would be much shallower than the *deep cracks* at the back & sides (where we'd be "deep-mining" higher-value treasure - maybe silver coins rather than just coppers! :)

Comment: @hearth abrupt changes like that are often due to one specific usage which gets repeatedly referenced in other documents. Same thing happens today with blog and forum posts.

Answer (score 7):

Crevice is fine for a narrow gap in general. It's not particularly rare word (it is something I'd expect most children to know), but in this exact situation I'd merely say "stuck down the side/back of the sofa"

[*Down the back of the chair*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_k4imlNGSrQ)

Comment: "crevice" actually comes *last* in my "beauty contest" NGram!

Comment: Except for a blissful time from the mid-60's to the early 70's.

Comment: @Chris: Gosh! Thanks to the magic of screen zoom, I see you're quite right! But that's really because I included ***the*** in my wildcard search. [Without it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+between+the+cushions&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20), ***crevice*** is nowhere to be seen - just *from / down / in / wedged / it / hand / **crack** (space and spaces!* :)

Comment: And [*here's another of **crevice's** brief spells in the limelight*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=down+the+crack+in+the%2Cdown+the+crevice+in+the&year_start=1870&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) From 1908 to 1919, *down the **crevice** in the [whatever]* was actually more common than *down the **crack...***

Comment: Automobile detailers and frequent users of vacuum cleaners all know of "crevice tools" so how can that be rare wordage or escape the ngram algorithms? Indeed the crevice tool tip is exactly intended to suck up little bits of late night snacking debris and lint, cat hair and tax free loot from those sofa and couch cushions.

Comment: @civitas: The word ***crevice*** isn't "rare" - as James says, we'd expect *most* children to know it. It's just nowhere near as common as ***crack*** in most contexts where either word could be used. And a ["vacuum cleaner **crack** tool"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22vacuum+cleaner+crack+tool%22) *isn't* one of those contexts - that one's always a ["**crevice** tool".](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22vacuum+cleaner+crevice+tool%22) (But children aren't the target customers or users for such things, so it wouldn't matter if they didn't know the word anyway! :)